# What else should I add/deduce from the code of animation?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

It's another question on animation in JS / CSS.

I'd like to ask how should I correct the code in JavaScript, in order to achieve the visual effect that, after a screen full of random characters, all the lines of random characters will disappear, with only the black background, while a new line of random characters starts generating at the top of the screen? I thought it would be a solution that, after the characters in the div element fill up the whole screen, the height can be a reference to trigger the function of `.removeChild()`, in order to remove the appended p elements. After that, by `.appendChild()` it will start the generation process again at the top of the screen. If not so, Is there any other ways to do it?

Thank you very much!

**Code:**

```js
function create_random_string(string_length) {
  var random_string = '';
  var characters = 'ABCDEFGabcdefg';

  for (var i, i = 0; i < string_length; i++) {
    random_string += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * characters.length));
  }
  return random_string;
}

let divElem = document.getElementById('container');
NewLine();

var MyInterval = setInterval(NewLine, 11000);

function NewLine() {
  let text = document.createElement("p");
  text.setAttribute("id", "text");
  text.innerHTML = create_random_string(15);
  divElem.appendChild(text);
}

function RemoveChild() {
  if (divElem.clientHeight > window.innerHeight) {
    while (divElem.firstChild) {
      divElem.removeChild(divElem.firstChild)
    };
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #000000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

#container {
  place-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 7.5vh;
}

#text {
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
  font-size: 4vw;
  letter-spacing: 3vw;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #ffffff;
  position: relative;
}

#text::before,
#text::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#text::before {
  background: #000000;
  animation: typewriter 10s steps(15) forwards;
}

#text::after {
  width: 0.125em;
  bottom: 0vh;
  Top: 0vh;
  background: #ffffff;
  animation: TypingBar 10s steps(15) forwards, blink 750ms steps(15) infinite;
}

@keyframes typewriter {
  0% {
    left: 0;
  }
  6.7% {
    left: 7vw;
  }
  100% {
    left: 90vw;
  }
}

@keyframes TypingBar {
  0%,
  6.7% {
    left: 8vw;
  }
  99.99% {
    left: 89.5vw;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  /* escape fade-in effect */
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  /* hide trailing cursor */
}

@keyframes blink {
  to {
    background: transparent;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <p id="text"></p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function create_random_string(string_length) {
  var random_string = '';
  var characters = 'ABCDEFGabcdefg';

  for (var i, i = 0; i < string_length; i++) {
    random_string += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * characters.length));
  }
  return random_string;
}

let divElem = document.getElementById('container');
NewLine();

var MyInterval = setInterval(NewLine, 11000);

function NewLine() {
  RemoveChild();
  let text = document.createElement("p");
  text.setAttribute("id", "text");
  text.innerHTML = create_random_string(15);
  divElem.appendChild(text);
}

function RemoveChild() {
  if (divElem.clientHeight > window.innerHeight) {
    divElem.innerHTML ="";
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #000000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

#container {
  place-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 7.5vh;
}

#text {
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
  font-size: 4vw;
  letter-spacing: 3vw;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #ffffff;
  position: relative;
}

#text::before,
#text::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#text::before {
  background: #000000;
  animation: typewriter 10s steps(15) forwards;
}

#text::after {
  width: 0.125em;
  bottom: 0vh;
  Top: 0vh;
  background: #ffffff;
  animation: TypingBar 10s steps(15) forwards, blink 750ms steps(15) infinite;
}

@keyframes typewriter {
  0% {
    left: 0;
  }
  6.7% {
    left: 7vw;
  }
  100% {
    left: 90vw;
  }
}

@keyframes TypingBar {
  0%,
  6.7% {
    left: 8vw;
  }
  99.99% {
    left: 89.5vw;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  /* escape fade-in effect */
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  /* hide trailing cursor */
}

@keyframes blink {
  to {
    background: transparent;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <p id="text"></p>
  </div>
</body>
```